# how do I send some headers with requests using uget?

Tags: uget

To download a specified file I need to pass a custom header to the server along with the request but I don't know how to do that using [uGet](http://ugetdm.com/), Is there any way to achieve this?

Note: uget is a graphical download manager that uses gtk2 and libcurl (a `curl` component).

Comment: Which header do you want to send?

Comment: @AnwarShah, well I didn't mean to ask for an specific header, it 's a custom one meant for additional custom security

Comment: After going through Uget manual page and it's website, I found that you can use http referrer flag. I see no option for using a custom flag http://ugetdm.com/documentation/tutorials

Comment: @DavidFoerster with your suggestion, I'm making that an answer. I'll remove it if anyone can prove it wrong in reasonable time period. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After going through Uget manual page and it's website, I found that you can use http referrer flag. But, I see no other option for using a custom flag for specifying custom HTTP headers.

- The Tutorial - http://ugetdm.com/documentation/tutorials
- Feature Listing - http://ugetdm.com/features which doesn't specify anything like custom header
- ManPage - http://ugetdm.com/manpage